# Why do these headers only work outside of the pre-compiled header?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In stdafx.h:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
```

In example.cpp:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
std::ifstream in_stream;
std::stringstream st_stream;
```

If I don't place the fstream and sstream includes in the .cpp file I get a ton of errors, such as:

```
Error   C2079   'in_stream' uses undefined class 
'std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'

Error   C2228   left of '.exceptions' must have class/struct/union
```

Why do the errors disappear if I place the appropriate includes directly in the .cpp file? Shouldn't the functionality be identical?

Comment: `<stdafx.h>` is not a standard C++ header.  Please tag your question with the appropriate compiler that you're using.

Comment: Due to the fact of they way <filename> does not compile the same why as "filename".

Comment: Read http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2z86b7Xj/ for a tutorial on how to use `stdafx.h`.

Comment: You have have included it in the wrong place in `stdafx.h`, or have your dependencies somewhat messed up, so your pre-compiled header didn't get re-compiled when it needed to (a frequent problem, because pre-compiled headers have some unique challenges in this respect). As a starting point, however, you might want to look at the documentation for [#pragma hdrstop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hdrstop).

Answer (score 1):

This should be written as `"stdafx.h"` not `<stdafx.h>`, because `"stdafx.h"` is not a standard header file (that's just C++ ethics, not rules).

Visual Studio automatically creates this files and adds a bunch of header files to it.

If you have a large project with many source files, and `<fstream>` is used in many source files, then include `<fstream>` in `"stdafx.h"`. Otherwise avoid editing this file.

`std::ifstream` requires `<fstream>` header files. The required header file is mentioned in relevant help pages. See for example [`std::ifstream help`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Add the relevant header files directly in your `"myfile.cpp"` file:

```
//myfile.cpp:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
int main(){...}
```

If you have a small project you can tell Visual Studio to stop using precompiled headers via "Project Settings" -> "C/C++" -> "Precompiled Headers". This way you can remove `"stdafx.h"` and your source file will be more compatible with different compilers.